# How to add dots to mark each step of this slider control?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I've modified the [Slider UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) from [jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) and now looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/eBukn/90/

```
.ui-slider-handle{
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ecf0f1  !important;
    line-height: 40px  !important;
    top: -15px !important;
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    background:#16a085 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-transition:background .25s ease-in;  
   -moz-transition:background .25s ease-in;  
   -o-transition:background .25s ease-in;  
   transition:background .25s ease-in;  
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
}

.ui-slider-handle:hover{
    background:#2fe2bf !important;
}

.ui-slider-handle:active{
   background:#16a085 !important;
}

.ui-slider-handle:focus{
   outline: none !important;
}

.ui-slider-range {
    background:#1abc9c !important;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.ui-slider{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
    border: none !important;
    background:#e8edf2 !important;
}
```

Forget the css, I did a quick customization and perhaps it has some mistakes... Anyway, what I'm trying to do is put black dots in each step so the user'll be able to see where will be the next step and the amount of it. Like in the image bellow.

[image: Here is a simulation]

What would be the best way to do it? 
First I thougth to put and element with jquery and repeat it n times (deppending the number of steps). But may be it's possible to do with pure CSS.

Do you have any idea or advice?

Comment: Adding a span/div for each step (and customize its style) seems the easiest solution. Can you do it?

Comment: I tried it, but I'm afraid I can't put them in its proportional place...

Comment: If you put all span elements into a div, then `display: inline-block` plus `margin-right` should works. Of course you need to do place the parent div in a coherent way

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try it and i put the fiddle here so you can tell me if i'm doing it well. :)

Comment: I am close to it... look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/eBukn/106/. But if I want the dots will be responsives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ok?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/V32MD/1/

**CSS**

```
.dots{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var foo = total - 1;
var mar = $( ".ui-slider" ).width() / foo;

for (var x = 0; x < foo; x++){

    $(".ui-slider" ).append("<span class='dots' style='left:"+ x * mar + "px'></span>");
}
```

You can use percentage an em's too: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/V32MD/2/

Comment: Oh! you are welcome!. Btw, it can be done using an image repeat-x (with the correct space) or even in a very CSS3 bleeding edge way using something like http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns

Comment: Ok, i take note. ;) By the by, this sliderui does not work in my mobile, any solution to this?

Comment: Hey friend, look at this that I found: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch#readme Now it works on my phone too! http://jsfiddle.net/V32MD/8/ Did you know it?

Comment: "touch punch" sounds familiar but I've not use it, is working fine?. Maybe I'll need a slider for a mobile web app soon.

Comment: yes it works! tested in my iphone and in my android tablet. ;)